# How to make a for-loop create new columns with info on whether each value is lower or higher than the column mean?

Tags: r, for-loop

I hope you all have a nice Friday.

I work in R, where I've had some problems trying to get a for-loop to work. I have a data frame where columns contain expression data for a number of genes, and rows represent different patients. I want to add a column for each gene showing if the patient has an expression above median.

```
geneA <- c(2,4,1,1,2,5)
geneB <- c(1,1,3,2,2,1)
geneC <- c(3,4,3,5,7,4)

expressiondata<- as.data.frame(cbind(geneA, geneB, geneC))
```

The result I'm trying to achieve is this:

```
geneA_median <- ifelse(geneA>median(geneA), 1,0)
geneB_median <- ifelse(geneB>median(geneB), 1,0)
geneC_median <- ifelse(geneC>median(geneC), 1,0)

expressiondata<- cbind(expressiondata, geneA_median, geneB_median, geneC_median)
```

However, I'm messing up when I try to make the loop go through both the columns and the rows. Does anyone have an idea of how I should do? I would be grateful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for loops, vectorized code only will do it.

```
expressiondata <- data.frame(geneA, geneB, geneC)

mu <- sapply(expressiondata, median)
df2 <- cbind(expressiondata, +t(t(expressiondata) > mu))
names(df2)[4:6] <- paste(names(df2)[4:6], "_median")
df2
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This help was worth a lot to me. I definitely need to practice more on vectorized code :) I hope you have a great weekend!

Answer (score 0):

One does not need to loop through the rows to calculate the vectors of "above median" indicators.

```
expressiondata <- data.frame(geneA = c(2,4,1,1,2,5),
                             geneB = c(1,1,3,2,2,1),
                             geneC = c(3,4,3,5,7,4))


# process with a loop, using vectorized math
for(i in c("geneA","geneB","geneC")) {
     expressiondata[[paste0(i,"_median")]] <- ifelse(expressiondata[i]>median(expressiondata[[i]]), 1,0)
}
```

...and the output as viewed thru the RStudio viewer:

[image]

We can extend the solution by extracting the column names from the original data frame within the `for()` loop to process all of its columns.

```
# extend the solution by using column names from original data frame
for(i in colnames(expressiondata)) {
     expressiondata[[paste0(i,"_median")]] <- ifelse(expressiondata[i]>median(expressiondata[[i]]), 1,0)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
expressiondata <- expressiondata %>%
  mutate(geneA_median = case_when(geneA > median(geneA) ~ 1,
                                  TRUE ~ 0),
         geneB_median = case_when(geneB > median(geneB) ~ 1,
                                  TRUE ~ 0),
         geneC_median = case_when(geneC > median(geneC) ~ 1,
                                  TRUE ~ 0))
```